# How to do multi-class image classification in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Here is what I did. I got the code for dog/cat image classification and I compiled and ran and got 80% accuracy. I added one more class (aeroplane) folder to the train and validation folder. Made changes in the following codes

```python
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
```

changed `binary class_mode` to `categorical` and also loss to `categorical_crossentropy`. Also changed output layout `sigmoid` to `softmax`.
 Receives the following error.

```python
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_10 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (16, 3)
```

Do I need to explicity change the training labels to categorical like mentioned below? (I read this from the site [multilabel classification using keras](http://www.codesofinterest.com/2017/08/bottleneck-features-multi-class-classification-keras.html))

```python
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes=num_classes)
```

I am not sure what happens here. Please help. I am relatively new to deep learning.

model

```python
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')


validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For multi-class classification, the last dense layer must have a number of nodes equal to the number of classes, followed by `softmax` activation, i.e. the last two layers of your model should be:

```python
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Additionally, your labels (both train and test) must be one-hot encoded; so, assuming that your initial cats and dogs were labeled as integers (0/1), and your new category (airplane) is initially similarly labeled as '2', you should convert them as follows:

```python
train_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes)
test_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(test_labels, num_classes)
```

Finally, on a terminology level, what you are doing is *multi-class*, and not multi-label classification (I have edited the title of your post) - the last term is used for problems where a sample might belong to more than one categories at the same time.

Comment: I need not had to change it to categorical since i was using my own image dataset as the input. changing to "samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples" instead of "steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size" solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For the multi-class classification, the size of the last layer of a NN must be equal the number of classes.

F.i. for your problem (3 Classes), the code should look like this:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Comment: `softmax` is not the correct activation function to be used for multi-label classification

Comment: You are confusing yourself with multi-calss and multi-label classification. Multi-label  means that an image can belong to more than one classes. If you put a softmax layer at the end, you are saying the probability of one class depends on the other classes.

Comment: No, I'm not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function -> `The softmax function is used in various multiclass classification methods`

Comment: also here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/

Comment: You are just blindly citing links without understanding what I am saying. `The softmax function is used in various multiclass classification methods`. Yes, `softmax` is for multi-class, **NOT** for multi-label

Comment: label == class in ML. Also, with the softmax activation function you can select top-5 probabilities, if you want. Besides, you can see the softmax activation function is the normalised sigmoid.

Comment: Why bringing multi-label into discussion in the first place? Is there anything in the question indicating multi-label? Or you are simply confusing multi-class with multi-label, which, as @AkshayLAradhya has been arguing correctly, are *different* things?

Comment: because class and label is the same thing in ML, but for you my friend I will edit my answer.

Comment: Please, instead of offering ready-made statements that means little, try to *listen*: "*Multi-label classification is a generalization of multiclass classification*" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification But in *this* question OP says nothing for multi-label